# java decode json help (using json-simple)

Tags: java, json, decode, json-simple

I know that asking for making something is bad but it's first time I'm stucked in java. Recently I began to learn java and for my small tool I need to read this json string.

Half a day I was searching and trying to make things work and founded json-simple.

But i cant do this.
Please help.

For example just retrieve steamid and communityvisibilitystate to strings

```
String steamid = ...;
String communityvisibilitystate = ...;
```

and if you have better solution not using json-simple post it

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198777777777",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "777777",
            "lastlogoff": 7777777777,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198777777777/",
            "avatar": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/16/777777777.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/16/777777777_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/16/777777777_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 0,
            "primaryclanid": "103582797777777777",
            "timecreated": 7777777777
        }
    ]

}
}
```

Comment: you should try googe's gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ here is simple guide how to use it https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 : your complete response is a JSON OBJECT

2 : if any element is written like

```
"some key name " : { " some value " }
```

this is a JSON Object

3 : if any element is writen like

```
 "some key name " :  " some value "
```

this is value inside you json object which you can get by

```
jsonObject.getString("key name")
```

4 : if any element is writen like

```
"some key name " : [ " some value " ]
```

then this is a JSON Array and you have to take it in to a JSON ARRAY and then traverse its elements by

```
jsonObject.getJSONARRAY("key name for JSON ARRAY IN RESPONSE ")
```

and then you can traverse the elements of the JSON ARRAY by

```
`jsonArrayObj.get(0);`
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your Question .It seems you have 2 problem

> To generate JSON online for that I would like to suggest you to Visit this [Link](http://www.json-generator.com) . this will generate the required JSON what you want.
>
> for parsing the json  see the below codes
> suppose you have put this JSON response in String Variable result

```
            String result = "yourresponse";

            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("response");
                JSONArray arr = object1.getJSONArray("Players");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) 
                {
                      JSONObject object3 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                      String steamId = object3.getString("steamid");
                      String communityvisibilitystate = object3
                        .getString("communityvisibilitystate");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do sthing like this:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\test.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

String steamid= (String) jsonObject.get("steamid");
System.out.println(steamid);
```

But i recommend using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It is much easier, and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class Result with the exact same structure as your json response (see below structure, for example)

```
class Result {
    class Response {
        list of (<class Players> {
             String steamid
             String communityvisibilitystate
             String profilestate
             String personaname
             String lastlogoff
             String profileurl
             String avatar
             String avatarmedium
             String avatarfull
             String personastate
             String primaryclanid
             String timecreated
             })
       }
   }
}
```

Then use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse your json like this.

```
Result pareseJson = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Result.class);
```